# How to delete records from multiple database with one button

Tags: php, mysql

I searched around and got close, but no cigar. I can make this work with only one database, though I am attempting to delete all records (without deleting the row structure) from 3 databases with one button. When I try to do this with 3 databases, I get "Page is not working" and no error codes. Any thoughts on what I'm missing? Below is my codes and thank you all for any assistance.
The button is on delete1.php and passes to delete2.php

**UPDATE 2: Okay so now with this update on both pages, I get zero errors however it will only list the entries in the first database, and also will only empty the entries on the first database. Any thoughts?**

https://www.peredy1.com/select/delete1.php

Delete1.php

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body text="#FFFFFF" bgcolor="#000000" link="#FFFF00" vlink="#FFFF00" alink="#FFFF33">
    <font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> 
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15" ></font>
    <p> <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = " ";
    $password = " ";
    $dbname = "vbauyvmy_randomname";
    
    
    $servernameA = "localhost";
    $usernameA = " ";
    $passwordA = " ";
    $dbnameA = "vbauyvmy_reqlinksbu";
    
    
    $servernameB = "localhost";
    $usernameB = " ";
    $passwordB = " ";
    $dbnameB = "vbauyvmy_ppreq_busend";
    
    
    
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    
    $sql = "SELECT id, name, band, song, extra, band2, song2, extra2, band3, song3, extra3 FROM nametable";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    
    
    $resultt = mysqli_query($conn, "select COUNT(id) AS count FROM `nametable`");
    
    if(!$result) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
    } else {
        $num_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultt);
        // echo it
        echo "<font color='red'>Total Songs</font>: <font color='yellow'><b>" . $num_rows['count']."</font></b></br></br>";
    }
    
    
    
    $connA = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($connA->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $connA->connect_error);
    }
    
    $sql = "SELECT id, name, band, song, extra, band2, song2, extra2, band3, song3, extra3 FROM nametable";
    $result = $connA->query($sql);
    
    
    $resultt = mysqli_query($connA, "select COUNT(id) AS count FROM `nametable`");
    
    if(!$result) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
    } else {
        $num_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultt);
        // echo it
        echo "<font color='red'>Total Songs</font>: <font color='yellow'><b>" . $num_rows['count']."</font></b></br></br>";
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    $connB = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($connB->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $connB->connect_error);
    }
    
    $sql = "SELECT id, name, band, song, extra, band2, song2, extra2, band3, song3, extra3 FROM nametable";
    $result = $connB->query($sql);
    
    
    $resultt = mysqli_query($connB, "select COUNT(id) AS count FROM `nametable`");
    
    if(!$result) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
    } else {
        $num_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultt);
        // echo it
        echo "<font color='red'>Total Songs</font>: <font color='yellow'><b>" . $num_rows['count']."</font></b></br></br>";
    }
    
    
    
    ?> 
      <input type="submit" id="deletebutton" name="deleteall" value="Reset Show">
    
    <br>
      <?php
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    
    
    
    
    
    if(!empty($row["name"])  ){
        echo " ";
      }
    
    
    if(!empty($row["band2"]) && !empty($row["song2"])  ){
        echo " ";
      }
    
    
    
    if(!empty($row["band3"]) && !empty($row["song3"])  ){
        echo " ";
      }
    
    
    
    
    
    
      }
    } else {
      echo "0 Records";
    }
    
    $connB->close();
    ?> </p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#deletebutton").click(function(){
      if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete all record?")){ 
        /* user clicked "OK" */ 
        location.href = "delete2.php";
    } 
    else { 
     
    }
      });
    });
    
    </script>
```

delete2.php

```
    <?php
    
    
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "vbauyvmy_peredyrandom";
    $password = "Destined1!2";
    $dbname = "vbauyvmy_randomname";
    
    $servernameA = "localhost";
    $usernameA = "vbauyvmy_peredylinksbu";
    $passwordA = "Destined1!2";
    $dbnameA = "vbauyvmy_reqlinksbu";
    
    $servernameB = "localhost";
    $usernameB = "vbauyvmy_busendperedy";
    $passwordB = "Destined1!2";
    $dbnameB = "vbauyvmy_ppreq_busend";
    
    
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    //Connect DB
    //Create query based on the ID passed from your table
    //query : delete where id = $id
    // on success delete : redirect the page to original page using header() method
    
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    
    
    $connA = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$connA) {
        die("Connection A failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    
    
    $connB = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$connB) {
        die("Connection B failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    
    
    
    
    // sql to delete a record
    $sql = "DELETE FROM nametable"; 
    
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        mysqli_close($conn);
    
    } else {
        echo "Error deleting record";
    }
    
    
    if (mysqli_query($connA, $sql)) {
        mysqli_close($connA);
    
    } else {
        echo "Error deleting record";
    }
    
    
    if (mysqli_query($connB, $sql)) {
        mysqli_close($connB);
        header('Location: delete1.php'); 
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "Error deleting record";
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    ?>
```

Comment: You didn't use `$dbnameA`, and `$dbnameB`.

Comment: `$password = " ` doesn't have an ending quote. Did you miss that when copying here, or is it actually not closed? YOu're also missing a few closing braces

Comment: `TRUNCATE TABLE <table>` would be better than `DELETE FROM <table>`

Comment: @aynber yes I accidentally deleted that in the paste in here

Comment: If you want to delete all rows, what is `$id` for?

Comment: You're exiting the script in the `if` statement after the first deletion query.

Comment: @Barmar oh I see. I didn't realize I needed both of those on the button page (delete1.php) I was actually wondering if I needed any of those at all. I'll try adding those now

Comment: I'm talking about `delete2.php`.

Comment: To say what Barmar already told you, but in a different way, you need `}` after each of your `echo "Error deleting record";` statements to close those code blocks.

Comment: @Barmar I'm sorry Im not following what you mean by I didn't use them in delete2.php. As for what is the $id for, I'm not sure to be honest. I had one php page that has been working for just one database, so now I'm attempting to alter it to work for 3 databases.

Comment: You're wanting to delete all the data from all 3 tables, so`$id = $_GET['id'];` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Jerry thank you for that. I just added the } to each of them but I still get the "Page is not working" page

Comment: Check your server error logs to see if there is any information there.

Comment: You already had a `}` after the last of them; you probably have gone from not enough block closures to too many.

Comment: I just updated the post. Thanks to the help in here, I have it working with the first database but not the other 2 now. Also, the second and third are showing only the amount of entries from the first database as well

Comment: As Barmar mentioned, you're exiting the script when the first deletion is successful. You only go on to 2 if 1 is not successful, and 3 if 2 is not successful. Don't nest the if statements and don't exit out of the scripts until you have traversed all 3.

Comment: @aynber I'm staring at the script but I can't seem to know what you mean to fix it. I thought I was doing so good with this but I can see I have a lot more to learn.

Comment: Looks like you've already fixed the nesting, so that's no longer an issue. But in each `if` block, you have `header('Location: delete2.php'); exit;` This will exit the script immediately, so once it hits that for the first database, it will never be able to go to 2 and 3. Add those two lines to the end of the script, but you may want to add a flag for errors.

Comment: @aynber I got rid of the first 2 that you mentioned and now I get "This page isn’t workingwww.peredy1.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500" And by the way thank for all for all the help. This helps me learn this better.

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: @aynber and others, I updated the original post now. I think it's getting closer. I put the remaining issue in bold (sorry if the bold is not preferred here I can change that)

Answer (score 0):

I got it. And HUGE thanks to all of you for the help.

The problem was in all of the comments above AND...
I forgot to edit the A and B in the connections for both pages at

```
    $connA = new mysqli($servernameA, $usernameA, $passwordA, $dbnameA);
```

Thank you ALL SOOOOO MUCH I learned a lot on this one. I'm very greatful!

Answer (score -4):

One thing you can try is to add something to delete in your file `delete2.php`.

`$sql = "DELETE FROM nametable";` you are missing the data that should be deleted.

Between `DELETE` and `FROM` you have to add the data that should be deleted.

if you want to delete everything try this:

```
$sql = "DELETE * FROM nametable";
```

Comment: Right now I have  $sql = "DELETE FROM nametable";  is that not right?

Comment: This answer is not correct.

Comment: `DELETE` doesn't require a list of columns, since it deletes the whole row. `*` is allowed, but it's not required.